# Can /%year%/%monthnum%/%day%/ structure tags be added to custom post type permalinks?

Tags: custom-post-types, permalinks

Just wondering if anyone had tried using any of the structure tags available to post permalinks with custom post types... I'm moving my "listings" posts on a site I manage from a category hack under Posts to their own custom post type, but I'd like to still keep some sort of numeric date reference in the permalink structure. How difficult is that to set up?

Comment: This process, and other issues related to custom post type permalinks, are described more fully on the [Shiba Shake Blog](http://shibashake.com/wordpress-theme/custom-post-type-permalinks).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you should be able to use date based URLs by using the `permalink_epmask` parameter with your `register_post_type` call..

```
add_action('init', 'wpse14370_custom_init');
function wpse14370_custom_init() {
    $args = array(
        'public' => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'show_ui' => true, 
        'show_in_menu' => true, 
        'query_var' => true,
        'rewrite' => true,
        'capability_type' => 'post',
        'has_archive' => true, 
        'hierarchical' => false,
        'menu_position' => null,
        'permalink_epmask' => EP_DATE,
        'supports' => array('title','editor','author','thumbnail','excerpt','comments')
  ); 
  register_post_type('book',$args);
}
```

Not sure exactly how custom endpoints work, but it's supported according to the codex page.
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type

And because it's not documented, here's all the possible endpoint values(though i don't know specifically which are supported with custom post types)..

```
EP_NONE
EP_PERMALINK
EP_ATTACHMENT
EP_DATE
EP_YEAR
EP_MONTH
EP_DAY
EP_ROOT
EP_COMMENTS
EP_SEARCH
EP_CATEGORIES
EP_TAGS
EP_AUTHORS
EP_PAGES
EP_ALL
```

If that doesn't work correctly, maybe just setting `with_front` to true will be enough if you're already using date based permalinks.

Comment: I never looked into the endpoint mask rules before - that was an interesting exercise, but unfortunately not what I was looking for. Setting up endpoint masks when you register a post type enables different kinds of archives for that post type (and you can apparently define your own, which is very cool), but it doesn't affect the canonical permalink structure for posts in that post type.

Comment: When my "listings" were Posts in a special category, their permalink structure was __/2011/04/01/post-name__. After making them a custom post type, the permalink structure is __/listing/post-name__. Ideally I'd like something like __/listing/2011/04/09/post-name__. Not sure if its possible without a lot of work, though.

Comment: End points should enable you to do that, or at least the [trac ticket](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/12605) that discusses end points says as much.

Comment: Apparently setting `"with_front" => true` enables you to visit a post of a custom post type using any of the structure tags enabled in __"permalink_epmask"__. It doesn't seem to change the canonical permalinks returned with `get_permalink()`, however. So visiting __/listing/2011/04/09/post-name__ will just redirect to __/listing/post-name__.